# I am trying to add a video to my konami code and running into some trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently was asked in class to add Konami to an html webpage. The typical, up,up,down,down,left,right,left,right,b,a. And I did that just fine(However had to use a string because I couldn't seem to get an Array to work, maybe someone can give me a hint on that as well), but now I want to do more with it. I want to add a video URL, probably something from youtube, to play in 100% of the height and width of the page. I also want to ensure it has sound. I know chrome does something to ensure sound doesn't autoplay, so that's also another obstacle I think I need to overcome. Here is what I have so for:

I ended up updating my code and posted my new issue in a below comment, it is now that I can't make the video the full size of the html page.

```
    `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Konami Code</title>
        <style>
            /*iframe*/
            /*{*/
                /*position: relative;*/
                /*right: 0;*/
                /*bottom: 0;*/
                /*min-width: auto;*/
                /*min-height: auto;*/
            /*}*/
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Konami Code</h1>
       <div id="videoFrame"></div>

        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            "use strict";



            var konami = '3838404037393739666513';
            var userKeys = '';


               $(document).keydown(function (event)
                {
                    userKeys += event.keyCode;
                });
            $(document).keypress(function(e)
            {
                if(e.which == 13)
                {
                    if (userKeys == konami)
                    {
                        alert('Happy birthday, my son.')
                        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                        iframe.src = "img/soldier.mp4";
                        iframe.width = "712px";
                        iframe.height = "690px";
                        var videoDiv = document.getElementById('videoFrame');
                        videoDiv.appendChild(iframe);
                    }
                        else
                    {
                        alert('WRONG CODE')
                        userKeys = '';
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like `ytcropper.com` gives you a link to a raw video file, which is what a `<source>` tag expects. You should be able to use the embed code (which looks like it uses an `iframe`) from that site instead, but that probably won't be as easy to control as your own `<video>` tag would be.

Comment: Good catch, I did download the video manually from youtube, and linked it, however still no dice.

Comment: Was the video hosted somewhere, or were you just pointing to a local file? (e.g. `file://C:/whatever`)

Comment: I ended up fixing my issue, however now I have run into an issue with iframe, and am unable to get it to be fullscreen, or rather the full size of the page. I ended up downloading the video to an mp4, and it worked great, and I can pause it and such inside the video.